# How can I easily check in Python that all items in one list are included in the other list?

Tags: python, list, function, collections, counter

I found some solutions, but none of them are what I need.

For example:

```
list1 = ['a', 'b', 'c']
list2 = ['a', 'a', 'b', 'c']
```

`Counter(list1) == Counter(list2)` -> `True`, but I need `False` because of the double 'a' ////
`set(list1) == set(list2)` -> `True`, but I also need `False`.

I want to write a small code to search possible words from list.

example:

wordCollection = ["dog", "go", "home", "long"] ////
input characters: "NLGUCOBAD"

result: dog, go, long

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `all` in conjunction with a simple expression:

```
result = all((list1.count(x) == list2.count(x)) for x in list1)
```

`all` returns `True` if every item in the collection is `True`. It will alternatively return `False` when not every item is `True`.

For example:

```
all([True, True, True, True, True])
>>> True

all([True, False, True, True, True])
>>> False
```

With this in mind, you can check if the count of each element in `list1` is the same in `list2`. This is where the `list1.count(x) == list2.count(x)` comes from.